# compass: No such framework: "foundation"

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

I'm trying to use install zurbs foundation framework

I've got this gem installed: 
zurb-foundation (4.3.1)

From my project, I do:

```
 compass install foundation
```

I get:

```
No such framework: "foundation"
```

How do actually use the installed framework?

Answer (score 1):

The command is:

```
compass install -r zurb-foundation foundation
```

If you already have zurb-foundation installed then the command to create a new project using foundation is:

```
compass create <project-name> -r zurb-foundation --using foundation
```

If you are working with a project that already exists using foundation and sass you need the config.rb file in the root directory:

```
require 'zurb-foundation'
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
# line_comments = false


# If you prefer the indented syntax, you might want to regenerate this
# project again passing --syntax sass, or you can uncomment this:
# preferred_syntax = :sass
# and then run:
# sass-convert -R --from scss --to sass sass scss && rm -rf sass && mv scss sass
preferred_syntax = :scss
```

Ensure you have `require 'zurb-foundation'` at the top.  That's what solved it for me when I had an already existing project.

Comment: I am having the same issues with Susy. I get this error when intalling susy via `compass:Gem::LoadError on line ["2064"] of c: Unable to activate susy-2.1.2, because sas
s-3.2.19 conflicts with sass (~> 3.3.0)
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace`

Answer (score 0):

The following command should help, it's also stated in the docs [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html).

Found under "Creating your first project".

```
$ compass create <project-name> -r zurb-foundation --using foundation
```

*I should note this is to create a new project*

If it's adding to an existing project, perhaps you missed out the:

- Add require "zurb-foundation" to your config.rb file

Comment: I am indeed using an already existing project. The project has no ruby dependencies within itself. I'm just using compass to grab the sass files. So, I have no config.rb file. In this case, is it still possible to use the sass package?

Comment: You do need a config.rb, otherwise Compass has no idea where the library lives.

Comment: Yeah, as cimmanon mentions you do need a config.rb file.
You could run: "compass config" That will generate just the config dir & config.rb.
Then you edit the config.rb file to link the the correct paths on your existing project.